# Вернуть данные из mongodb без названия поля

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, nosql

Есть коллекция со списком сайтов:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "site" : "https://test.ru" }
{ "_id" : 2, "site" : "https://test1.ru" }
{ "_id" : 3, "site" : "https://test2.ru" }
```

При извлечении данных в Nodejs заношу наименования сайтов в массив:

```
function sites_promised(mongo_url){
      return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
      MongoClient.connect(mongo_url, function(err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        //Return only the "name" field in the result:
            var dbo = db.db("nameSites");
            dbo.collection("newsSites").find({}, options).toArray(function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            for(i=0;i<=3;i++){
                arrSites[i]=result[i];
            }
            db.close();
            resolve(arrSites);
            });
      });
      });
    }


 sites_promised(mongo_url).then(result => {
     console.log(result);
 });
```

На данный момент данные извлекаются в виде:

```
[ { site: 'https://test.ru' },
  { site: 'https://test1.ru' },
  { site: 'https://test2.ru' } ]
```

Необходимо, чтобы названия сайтов заносились в массив просто наименованиям, без имени поля, чтобы можно было дальше работать с этими данными. 
Версия mongodb 3.6.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы получаете массив "объектов" производите выборку соответственно arrSites[i]=result[i].site;

Comment: Спасибо большое!